# Questions about Makerspaces and 3-D Printers?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Are questions about 3-D printers and their use in makerspaces allowed, for example, "What are the best practices for the maintenance of 3-D printers in makerspaces?" and "What is the best software based solution for the operation of 3-D printers in makerspaces?" Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overall, you'll want to try and stay away from *"What is the best..."* type questions. However, I would say that services related to 3D printing should be okay. Please regard [Robert Cartaino's](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67/fdm-printer-that-can-also-mill-and-engrave-whats-in-scope/68#68) response on potential topics. He brings up a good point:

> *This is one of those times where I'd say it's not the "name" that defines this site, but the intentions of the community that built it.*

For the questions in mind, I think that questions related to discovering new "Makerspace"-type communities and sites would be appropriate. In the case of your software question. I would definitely highlight some key features, if you can, of what you might be looking for. For example:

- Plug and Play software
- Customizable G-Code
- Advanced control over parameters
- Dual-Extrusion capability
- Compatibility with a print server
- etc.

Information like this can make or break a *"What is the best..."* question.

Comment: What about a question like..."What maintenance issues have you seen in 3-D printers in Makerspaces?" or even "What type of maintenance is typically required when operating 3-D printers at high production?" Thanks in advance

Comment: @JRoibal Overall, I'd say go ahead ask the questions. It doesn't hurt to go ahead and ask these types of questions. If they don't quite adhere to what the community is looking for, the community will let you know by temporarily closing the question until we can agree on the best way to present your question.